# How can I get list of replies to my tweets using Tweetsharp or using any direct API

Tags: twitter, tweetsharp

I am trying to get list of tweet replies using TweetSharp. I actually need complete list of replies of last x tweets so I am using chain process to get list of tweets first and then their replies. Is there anyone else has done the similar thing? Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve a user's home timeline, replies to the tweets in that timeline are included, and you could pull the replies out that way.

However, the REST API does not appear to provide a method to return all of the replies to an individual tweet.

The streaming API may be more suited to this, but I have not worked with it.